# Detect change in Treeview

Tags: vb.net

I have a Treeview in a form. I can add a child node, delete nodes, shift a child node by creating a subfolder in the Treeview and also change text of any child node.

How can I determine programmatically, whether one of these events/changes was occur?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're going to struggle finding an event that will fire when you modify the TreeView's Nodes collection.

You may find your answer by controlling access to your TreeView's Nodes via some kind of wrapper functions or class that subsequently delegates to the TreeView but also raises the necessary events for you to hook into.